How can I write a script in the head of some of my Blazor pages?
I want to write event structured data in the <head> of some of my Blazor pages, where the content is specific to the page.
So it is:
<head>
    <script type="application/ld+json">
        /* 15 - 30 lines of JSON */
    </script>
</head>

This would get added to App.razor I think.
Do I put a string [CascadingParameter] in App.razor.cs, set it as @MyEventScript in App.razor, and then assign it in the child @Body MyPage.razor.cs?
I'm asking for what is a supported way to do this. (Not the opinion "best", but what approach is using supported functionality in Blazor and therefore will continue to work in future versions.)

Placing content in the <head> is simple. Just place it inside a <HeadContent> in the razor page.
With that said, if this content is for the Google web crawler, the dynamic data will not be there when it is read (see details here).
